# Raise specificity of * selector

Tags: css

I am creating a chrome extension that makes webpages a certain font. I have a content script that appends this as a style element in the head of the document but on some sites the font still does remains the same. How would I be able to raise the specificity of this so that I it would be able to override any other css rule?

```
*
{
  font-family: Arial !important; 
}
```

An example of a site that it does not work on: https://dailyiowan.com/2021/12/07/4-best-linux-based-router-os-that-you-can-install-right-now/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that some sites set their font with `!important` so that you cannot override it.

Obviously you cannot increase the specificity by adding a bigger "path" (as in more classes, tags or ids) to the selector, because you do not know them.

So the only way I see to force your font is by applying the style as inline-style with javascript.

`style="font-family: Arial !important"`

This should always override other styles.

Comment: I was wondering if there were tricks or features in css that I didn't know about but maybe there aren't. A trick I came across that I thought could work was duplicate selectors but in my testing it did not work with the * selector. https://www.tobymackenzie.com/blog/2016/05/10/duplicate-selectors-increase-specificity/

Comment: I looked at your example again and I noticed that it also applies styles on an ID, which has a higher specificity than other elements. I don't think you can solve this without using any JS. But with JS I assume you could prepare an styled ID and apply that to a wrapping element. Which obviously fails if the element already has an ID. I am afraid I don't think there is an elegant solution to solve this. Also notice that some icons wont work due to "icon fonts" being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

> The universal selector (*) and the pseudo-class :where() and its parameters aren't counted when calculating the weight, but they do match elements. The value for both the universal selector and the pseudo-class is 0-0-0; these selectors do not impact the specificity weight value.

So, you would need to increase specificity by targeting something more specific in your css rules.

- ID : it adds 1-0-0 to the weight value.
- CLASS column: it adds 0-1-0 to the weight value.
- TYPE column: it adds 0-0-1 to the weight value.

There are some tricks you can add to increase the specificity value, for instance, duplicating the selector value like in the next example:

```
#myId#myId#myId span { /* 3-0-1 */}
.myClass.myClass.myClass span { /* 0-3-1 */ }
```

So, there you have it, you need to be more specific applying your css rules in order to make them override other competing rules.
For more details I recommend you to give it a read to the Specificity section in MDN web docs.